# How to add next line to previous line after a blank line in unix shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a unix file like below

```
abcdge
efg
bh

ggh
bhj
mkl
```

---

I want to change the file and make it like:

```
abcdge
efg
bhggh
bhj
mkl
```

means: after each blank line, the next line should be append with previous line. How can i achieve it?

Comment: George I have edited your question for readability but I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  Can you please just ensure my edits are correct.  Thanks and sorry if they aren't.  FYI please see the [help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) section for information on asking questions.

Comment: @Jesse_b It seems to me that "after each blank file," should be "after each blank **line**,"

Comment: @guillermochamorro: Thanks, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -e '
    $!N;$q;N
    s/\n\n//
    P;D
 ' file
```

Maintain 3 lines inn the pattern space and remove the consecutive newlines when seen.

Answer (score 2):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '1;END{print"\n"}' RS= ORS= file
abcdge
efg
bhggh
bhj
mkl
```

Comment: Can you explain it, what does `1`, mean?

Comment: It's the extremely common awk idiom of specifying a true condition to invoke the default action of printing the current record. It's equivalent to writing `{print $0}` and you'll find it used in many, many awk scripts.

Comment: `awk '1' RS= ORS= file; echo` appears to work just as well

Comment: @bu5hman ok but there's no point adding additional commands and if you were going to pipe that output to some other command then it gets complicated and you have to consider which shell constructs to use and if you want it to run in a subshell or not, etc. If you can do it simply in one command then just do that.

Comment: Was only an observation, and perhaps a little golf, but I did like your `awk` use.

Comment: It fails if the size of bytes greater than 3000. How to resolve that?

Comment: "It fails" is the worst possible way to ask for help with any problem. Always say in what way "it fails" - no output, wrong output, core dump, error messages, etc.? In this case the script reads one block of blank-line separated text at a time and simply prints each block as it sees it so I find it extremely unlikely that it's running out of memory or other resources no matter how big your input file is.

Comment: The file size is 31MB. When I am running this command on this file size, it stating: awk: Input line  cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes.

Comment: Google is your friend - [https://www.google.com/search?q=awk%3A+Input+line+cannot+be+longer+than+3%2C000+bytes](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk%3A+Input+line+cannot+be+longer+than+3%2C000+bytes). Get gawk.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
sed -z 's/\n\n//g' file
```

Output:

```
abcdge
efg
bhggh
bhj
mkl
```

Comment: Quite clever, although it's good to know possible limitations. I think this approach makes `sed` read and process any text file as one "line". This may be sub-optimal (or fail?) if the file is huge. And the command cannot be used as a real-time filter for a "neverending" text stream.

Comment: Right and it should be stated that it's GNU sed only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<file awk '
   {
   if (n && $0!="")
      printf "\n"
   if ($0=="")
      n=""
   else
      {n=1; p=1; printf "%s", $0;}
   }
   END {if (p) printf "\n"}
 '
```

Each non-empty line is printed without its terminating newline character. Before this happens, if the current line is not empty and the previous line was not empty, a newline character gets printed; so in these circumstances the previous line becomes complete.

Finally, if any non-empty line was printed, one newline character terminates the last incomplete line and makes it complete.

`n` and `p` are markers indicating "non-empty last line" and "something was printed" respectively.

Consecutive empty lines are equivalent to one empty line. I don't know if this behavior is what you want.

The solution should work well as a filter (i.e. in a pipe). If you need it to modify the input file, check this: [*Save modifications in place with `awk`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/10765659).

Comment: Always use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` as the former just uses whatever value `ORS` has while the latter is hard-coding the value that ORS is assumed to have. And it saves you 3 chars :-).